# How should I be working with folders in Python?

Tags: python

I have a series of zip files that contain PDFs and a varying amount of images. These PDFs contain different addresses that I want to use as the basis for renaming the extracted files. I have created a series of functions that leave me with the string of the address.

I'm now trying to create the folders based off those names, but I'm getting a `FileNotFoundError` despite the folder existing.

Here's the relevant code:

```
with os.scandir('.') as folders:
    for folder in folders:
        if folder.is_dir():
            os.chdir(folder)
            for item in os.listdir('.'):
                extension = ".pdf"
                if item.endswith(extension):
                    os.mkdir('test')
                os.chdir('..')
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 109, in <module> os.chdir(folder)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './zip'
```

I'm a new programmer so any and all advice is welcome but I'm specifically wondering:

- Why am I encountering this error when the directory exists.
- If this is the way I should be working with directories in Python at all, or if my approach is completely wrong.

Comment: So what's your question exactly? Your description is not about efficiency, but your title is.

Comment: Use os.walk https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.walk (it also exists in python 2.7)

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle You're right, let me revise the title and flesh out the question; my question is better worded 'How should I be working with folders in Python?'

Comment: The `os.('.')` can't be valid.

Comment: import `os.path` and look into the documentation for how to work with paths better.

Comment: Instead of using os.walk & scandir, look at the newer "pathlib" module. A cheat sheet is here: https://pbpython.com/pathlib-intro.html

Comment: @martineau You're right, I lost the ".listdir" when copying.

Comment: Are you getting a `FileNotFoundError` or is it a `FileExistsError`? I ask because that's what `os.mkdir()` will raise if the directory already exists (and you've never indicated on what line the error occurs).

Comment: Hi @martineau, it's a FileNotFound:```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 109, in <module>
    os.chdir(folder)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './zip'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to search for file and [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) in general for paths. 
Glob is also build in pathlib. You can search you directories by:

```
Path('.').glob('**/*')
```

And then use other methods from pathlib to identify extension, folders and to make folders.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally sure what causes the error, but I was able to reproduce it, and discovered that changing the argument passed to `scandir()` as shown below avoids the `FileNotFoundError` exception.

I *think* it's got something to do with changing the current directory with `os.chdir()` inside the loop.

**Note:** Since it is possible for there to be more than one `".pdf"` file in the same subdirectory, the `os.mkdir('test')` could fail because one named `'test'` already exists — so you should check whether one already exists before attempting to create it again.

```
import os

with os.scandir(os.path.abspath('.')) as folders:  # Change line to this.
    for folder in folders:
        if folder.is_dir():
            os.chdir(folder)
            for item in os.listdir('.'):
                extension = ".pdf"
                if item.endswith(extension):
                    os.mkdir('test')  # Could fail...
                os.chdir('..')
```